# VBA API Convert JSON response & place into Excel Sheet

Tags: json, excel, vba

I am not the greatest with vba coding.. some help will be much appreciated.

I have some code that I get via api and the response is returned in JSON. I need this converted so that it can then be inserted into cells. each request is a single response for one address. Please could some help with this.

Code I have done is below that works and gives me the correct response;

```
Sub api_request()

'Declare variables
Dim xml_obj As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60

'Create a reference to the Microsoft XML library
Set xml_obj = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60

'Define URL Components
base_url = "https://api.getaddress.io/find/"

param_postcode = InputBox("Postcode Here")
param_postcode_val = "/"

param_number = InputBox("Number or Name")
param_number_val = "/"

param_api = "?api-key="
param_api_Value = "dAAsSIXtn9iKsObVq3L1kA11823=true"

'Combine all the different components into a single URL
api_url = base_url + _
          param_postcode + param_postcode_val + _
          param_number + param_number_val + _
          param_api + param_api_Value
              
'Open a new request, specify the method and the URL
xml_obj.Open bstrMethod:="GET", bstrURL:=api_url

'Send the request
xml_obj.send

'Print the status response
Debug.Print xml_obj.responseText

    End
End Sub
```

This is the output response text;

> {"postcode":"MK13 0EZ","latitude":52.066448,"longitude":-0.783306,"addresses":[{"formatted_address":["10 Meads Close","","","New Bradwell, Milton Keynes","Buckinghamshire"],"thoroughfare":"Meads Close","building_name":"","sub_building_name":"","sub_building_number":"","building_number":"10","line_1":"33 Meads Close","line_2":"","line_3":"","line_4":"","locality":"New Bradwell","town_or_city":"Milton Keynes","county":"Buckinghamshire","district":"Milton Keynes","country":"England"}]}

I need this above output into a worksheet in excel and then any other requests that are done place under the above response and so on.. I really do hope that someone can help me.

Thanks

Comment: Look into https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON - Then use it to convert the JSON output into a Dictionary which you can then navigate through can do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I won't answer your question directly, but I'll give you a sub that I've used in the past to give you a framework.

1. Basic Request

   ```
    Dim XMLPage As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim HTMLDoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim Code As String
    Dim JSON As Object
    Dim Key As Variant

    Code = "500002"

    XMLPage.Open "GET", "https://api.bseindia.com/BseIndiaAPI/api/StockTrading/w?flag=&quotetype=EQ&scripcode=" & Code, False
    XMLPage.send

    Set JSON = JsonConverter.ParseJson(XMLPage.responseText)

    For Each Key In JSON
        Debug.Print Key & ": " & JSON(Key)
    Next Key
   ```

The link to the JSON converter has been provided by another user in the comments.